# How to terminate Firebase thread in Spring MVC app

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, firebase

I am using Firebase in a Spring MVC app in tomcat.
It seems firebase creates a non-daemon thread that prevents tomcat from shutting down.

How do I terminate/shutdown Firebase in my Spring app?

This is how I am using Firebase:

```
private static Firebase getUserRef(String username)
{
    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://<firebaseurl>"); 
    return ref.child(username);
}
private static void createUserName(final String name)
{
    final Firebase userref = getUserRef(name);
    userref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            Object value = dataSnapshot.getValue();
            // logic
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError)
        {

        }
    });
}
```

The `createUserName()` method is called inside a controller method.

Should I be using beans?

Comment: Show us how you are using Firebase. Do you declare beans? What's the Firebase entry point?

Comment: updated. as you can see, I am not using beans and not sure if I should be??

Comment: I don't know the `Firebase` API at all, but try adding a `ServletContextListener` with a `contextDestroyed()` method which calls [`Firebase.goOffline()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/Firebase.html#goOffline())

Comment: that is a possibility. but i am waiting for someone from firebase support to provide an official answer

Comment: Well according to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/ldkIbTIcZPk), it doesn't seem like there's an API call to kill the worker thread. Also, `Firebase.goOffline()` just closes network connections, it does nothing to the worker thread.

Comment: There is currently no officially documented way to kill the background thread (goOffline won't kill it, there's other parts of the SDK that use it). We might be able to figure out an undocumented (and thus unsupported way) to get at the thread manually...

Comment: so how is one supposed to gracefully shutdown a web app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue has been fixed as of v1.0.15 of the Firebase Java Client. You can download the latest version here:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-quickstart.html

Firebase now creates only daemon threads, so your process will exit cleanly as expected.

Comment: A comment from anonymous user: "You can call `Firebase.goOffline()` and Firebase will shut down all of its threads, allowing your process to exit cleanly."

Comment: This is not solved, the FirebaseDatabaseWorker thread never terminates on tomcat when App is undeployed:

apache-tomee-plus-7.0.1
firebase-server-sdk 3.0.1

WARNING - The web application [myApp] appears to have started a thread named [FirebaseDatabaseWorker] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

JVisualVM reports the FirebaseDatabaseWorker as parked.

I am calling firebase.goOffline() on a ServletContextListener.contextDestroyed method, but it does not release the FirebaseDatabaseWorker thead.

Comment: This is still not fixed, I am using version
com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.2.0

Comment: This is still not fixed in com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.5.0